# CKAN API calls via python using urllib2 gives HTTP Error 409: Conflict

Tags: python-2.7, ckan

Hi I have been trying to import a dataset using ckan api call via python's urllib2 following the documentation at http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/ 
the Code I am running is 
`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import urllib
import json
import pprint

dataset_dict = {
        'name': 'my_dataset_name5',
        'notes': 'A long description of my dataset',
}

data_string = urllib.quote(json.dumps(dataset_dict))

request = urllib2.Request(
        'http://<ckan server ip>/api/action/package_create')

request.add_header('Authorization', 'my api key')

response = urllib2.urlopen(request, data_string)
assert response.code == 200

response_dict = json.loads(response.read())
assert response_dict['success'] is True

created_package = response_dict['result']
pprint.pprint(created_package)`
```

However it gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "autodatv2.py", line 26, in
>   response = urllib2.urlopen(request, data_string)File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen return
>   opener.open(url, data, timeout)File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 437, in open response = meth(req, response)File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response 'http',
>   request, response, code, msg, hdrs) File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error return
>   self._call_chain(*args) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line
>   409, in _call_chain result = func(*args) File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
>   raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 409: Conflict

I am running CKAN version 2.4 with python 2.7.10 on a Amazon ec2 instance and 
echo $HTTP_PROXY shows nothing so I'm assuming it not a proxy issue.. 
Could someone please provide any help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CKAN is returning HTTP error 409, which could mean nearly anything. e.g You could have a missing field or there may be already a dataset of that name in the CKAN.

There will be an error message explaining the problem in the response body and also on in the CKAN log.

Frankly, using urllib2 is making life hard for yourself. To talk to the CKAN API in python, at the very least use 'requests', but best practice is to use https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi e.g.

```
import ckanapi

demo = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN('http://demo.ckan.org',
    apikey='phony-key',
    user_agent='ckanapiexample/1.0 (+http://example.com/my/website)')

pkg = demo.action.package_create(name='my-dataset', title='not going to work')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion..will try using that..BTW what does the _user_agent_ field signify?

Comment: I figured it out and the ckan api works as you said. I couldn't find any **documentation**  for the different arguments that can be passed to the **package_create**  function though do you know of any?

Comment: The fields are defined in `default_create_package_schema` https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/logic/schema.py#L103 however your CKAN plugins can customize this and you'd have to dig into the code to see the types of values. You're probably better creating some datasets with the CKAN web form, then looking at the resulting package JSON using the API's package_show, as guidance.